# Is prokaryotic chromosome really a chromosome?

Tags: cell-biology

As far as i know, chromosome is a highly compacted version of chromatin during mitosis. And chromatin is a complex consisting of DNA strand and histones for more effective storage of DNA.

And I'm heard(not actually 'learn' it) that chromatin is only found in eukaryotic cells and prokaryotic cells have a different organization of their DNA.

Taken together, prokaryotes don't have chromatin and don't have chromosome either since chromosome is a upgraded version of chromatin.

But many medium including books and internet sites call prokaryotic organization of DNA chromosome(especially E.coli chromosome)

Hence, my question is:

Is it just a wide use of chromosome term in prokaryotes? or my knowledge of chromatin and chromosome wrong?

*plus, I searched about this problem previously and am heard that the prokaryotic chromosome equivalent is called genophore. How about genophore?

Answer (score 1):

Initially, chromosomes got their name from the ability of eukaryotic metaphase chromosomes to bind certain dyes. [The word chromosome is Greek for "colored body".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosome#Etymology)

Nowadays, [the term chromosome refers broadly to a single DNA molecule](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/68002875), no matter the organism. Hence the term "*E. coli* chromosome".